# OFDM Channel Equalization Issue when Resampling

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

Noticing a strange problem when I upsample an OFDM symbol to a "transmit" sampling rate, pass it through a channel, and then downsample it back to its baseband sampling rate. After doing this, the equalization scheme (H = Y/X) no longer seems to work. I'm trying to follow [this method](https://openofdm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eq.html) (Sub-carrier Equalization and Pilot Correction).

In the figure below you can see the blue line does in fact look like the inverse of the channel response. But the orangeish line (the one that comes from the signal upsampled then downsampled) not longer inverts the channel response as expected. What could be causing this, perhaps some oversight on my part, but I'm stumped.

```
% long training symbol, 64 fft bins
lts  = zeros(1,64)
negF = (-26:1:-1) + 64
posF = 1:27
lts([negF posF]) = [ 1, 1, -1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1, ...   
     -1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1,    ...
     -1, 1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1,    ...
      1, 1,  0,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,    ...
     -1, 1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1,  ...
     -1, 1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1,...
     -1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

% channel response
chan = [.8,.000001, .0000001, .0000001, .1+.01j]; 

% RESAMPLE TO 12X THE BASEBAND RATE
in   = ifft(lts)
inu  = resample(in, 12,1)

% GO THROUGH CHANNEL 
out   = filter(chan,1, in)
outu  = filter(chan,1, inu)

% RESAMPLE TO 1/12X THE TX RATE
chan_out_d = resample(outu,1,12)
chan_out = out

H = fft(chan_out)./lts
Hd = fft(chan_out_d)./lts

figure
plot(fftshift(abs(1./H)))
hold on
plot(fftshift(abs(1./Hd)))
plot(fftshift(abs(fft(chan/max(chan),64))))
legend('inverse channel', 'inverse channel downsampled', 'channel','Location', 'Best')
```

[image]

Comment: needed to upsample the channel response for it to match, still not a 1-for-1 match, but much closer!

Comment: lts has a few zeros. That can not be good if you use 1/lts for channel estimation. It creates inf and -inf values in H and Hd.